# Prove that $|x| \geq a$ iff $x\leq -a$ or $x \geq a$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

So I want to prove that and its counterpart.
I have that

\begin{align*}
|x| \leq a \Longleftrightarrow -a \leq x \leq a
\end{align*}

$x \leq |x|$, and $|x| \leq a$, so for transivity, $a \geq x$, and then, $-a \leq -|x|$, $-|x| \leq x$, and $-a \leq x$.

The thing is I don't know how to prove from right to left with this one
\begin{align*}
|x|\geq a \Longleftrightarrow (x\leq -a)\vee(x \geq a)
\end{align*}

Can someone tell me a hint, or at least the next step?

Comment: I would just split it up into two cases: (1) assume $x\geq 0$ and (2) assume $x<0$. In case (1) we have $|x|=x$ and in case (2) we have $|x|=-x$.

Comment: You can square both sides and apply the difference of squares identity (assuming that $a \geq 0$):

$$|x| > a \Longleftrightarrow |x|^{2} > a^{2} \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} - a^{2} > 0 \Longleftrightarrow (x-a)(x+a) > 0$$

Comment: Just do it by definition.  If $x \ge 0$ and $|x| \ge a$ then $x = |x|$ and $x \ge a$.  If on the other hand if $x < 0$ and $|x| \ge a$ then $|x| =-x$.  And so $-x =|x| \ge a$. $-a \ge x$ and $x \le -a$.  That's all there is to it.